# Authenticate to geoserver using openlayers 2

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, javascript, php

I want load layers from geoserver using openlayers in php page.
How I should do it? Maybe can give ane code examples?
Layers not public, need authentification.

Comment: Do you mean this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950747/authenticate-in-geoserver-with-asp-net-and-iis/13123640#13123640